# C++ base class constructor taking derived class as argument (?)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance, constructor

Use case:

- **`Vector`** class (implementing some math) and a derived **`Vector2D`** class
- Both classes should ideally allow "copy construction" from each other

`Vector`

```
namespace mu {
template<std::size_t N, typename T>
class Vector {
  public:
  // ...

  template <typename... TArgs>
  Vector(TArgs... args) : data({args...}) {}

  Vector(const Vector &other) = default; // copy constructor

  // ...
  protected:
    std::array<T, N> data;
};
}
```

`Vector2D`

```
namespace mu {
template<typename T>
class Vector2D : public Vector<2,T> {

  public:

  using Vector<2, T>::Vector; // inherit base class constructors

  Vector2D(const Vector<2, T>& other) : Vector<2, T>(other) {}

  // Vector2D specific functions, e.g. rotation
  //...

};
}
```

*note: the actual classes contain a lot more but i condensed it down to the code that i think is most important here.*

The problem is that i'm not able to **implement a way such that a `Vector` can be constructed from a `Vector2D`**, see code below. All other cases work fine.

```
// Example 1 (compiles)
mu::Vector<2, int> a{1, 2};
mu::Vector<2, int> b{a};

// Example 2 (compiles)
mu::Vector2D<int> c{1, 2};
mu::Vector2D<int> d{c};

// Example 3 (compiles)
mu::Vector<2, int> e{1, 2};
mu::Vector2D<int> f{e};

// Example 4 (doesn't compile)  <-- how to get this to work?
mu::Vector2D<int> g{1, 2};
mu::Vector<2, int> h{g};
```

Of course the more general question would be if inheritance is the right way to structure these classes. But i'd like `Vector2D` to have all the functionality of `Vector` and also additional functions that the `Vector` does not have.

Comment: This data should not be organised as a class hierarchy. It doesn't really make a lot of sense to have a separate `Vector2D` class. A 2D vector is a `Vector<2, ..>` *and nothing more*. So it is a simple alias, not a whole new class. Or, alternatively `Vector2D` uses `Vector` as its *internal* representation (so containment, not inheritance).

Comment: i thought about this too, but Vector2D is not only a "typedef" of a Vector but has more specific functions that the Vector doesn't have. For example, it contains functions to rotate the Vector2D.

Comment: You can rotate a vector of any dimension, but this is beside the point. You are not the first person who tries to implement geometric vectors this way. Been there, done that. It doesn't work.

Comment: rotation? I know. not the first one? I'm sure i'm not. But why should it not work? Except for the little flaw that i can't use intialization as in Example 4, it works fine.

Comment: It doesn't work because there are many problems apart from this small initialisation issue. You may or may not encounter them in your particular application, but you should be aware that *in general* public inheritance works well for *identity based* objects and doesn't work all that well for *value based* objects.

Comment: Ah, i see what you're saying. However, i really don't want to re-implement / have lots of forwarding code which is what happens with composition. In that sense inheritance is much better.

Comment: I would recommend to rather implement all these additional functions that are specific tp 2D vectors as standalone non-member functions, and forget about the separate class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Vector` class has two constructor: a template one (intended for values) and the default copy constructor.

Problem: the copy constructor is preferred but only if there is an exact match.

So, initializing `b` with `a`

```
mu::Vector<2, int> a{1, 2};
mu::Vector<2, int> b{a};
```

the copy constructor is preferred because `a` is an exact match

But, initializing `h` with `g`

```
mu::Vector2D<int> g{1, 2};
mu::Vector<2, int> h{g};
```

`g` can be converted to a `mu::Vector<2, int>` but **isn't** an exact match, so the template constructor is preferred but the template constructor is incompatible.

A possible solution: SFINAE disable the template constructor when the there is only one argument and the argument is derived from `mu::Vector`.

For example

```
template <typename... TArgs,
          typename std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(TArgs) == N
                                or (not std::is_base_of_v<Vector, TArgs> && ...), int> = 0>
Vector(TArgs const & ... args) : data({args...}) {}
```

Comment: `!= 1`? Why? We have `N` there.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. - Well... maybe is unuseful... but this enable the constructor in the case there are two or more arguments, all derived from `Vector`.

Comment: You can just say `== N` there instead.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. - But with `== N` you forbid this: `mu::Vector<5, int> a{1, 2, 3};`,  where the internal `std::array<int, 5>` is initialized `{1, 2, 3, 0, 0}`, so with additional zeros for non expressed values. Given that the original code permit this, I prefer maintain this possibility.

Comment: I would rather disallow this because there's no real-world scenario where such thing is useful, but of course that's just my opinion.

Comment: my plan was to forbid code like `mu::Vector<5, int> a{1, 2, 3};` since i could see it being the source of simple bugs. Of course, also just my opinion

Comment: @mtosch - Is your code, so your opinion is the one that counts. I add the `== N` constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside suitability of inheritance for this specific task, the immediate reason for the failure is the catch-all `template <typename... TArgs>` constructor. It will intercept every construction which is not a copy—and construction from a derived class object is **not** a copy. This is because conversion from Derived to Base is a conversion, and the template constructor doesn't require a conversion, so it's a better match.

You want to restrict the catch-all constructor to only be included in overload resolution if the arguments are suitable for constructing the `std::array` member. This is a standard application of SFINAE.