# C++ SFINAE constructor accepting derived class too

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, constructor, sfinae

Primer: [C++ base class constructor taking derived class as argument (?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64634110/c-base-class-constructor-taking-derived-class-as-argument)

I have a `Vector` and a `Vector2D` class. The former should contain a constructor that allows element-wise type casting. It should be allowed for the derived class too. For some cases, it already works, (see examples below) but i think some SFINAE magic is what's missing.

`Vector`

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

namespace mu {
template<std::size_t N, typename T>
class Vector {
public:
    // ...

    template <typename... TArgs,
        std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(TArgs) == N ||
                         (!std::is_base_of_v<Vector, TArgs> && ...), int> = 0>
    Vector(TArgs... args) : data({args...}) {}

    // this should always be called for type casting:
    template <std::size_t Nn, typename Tt>
    Vector(const Vector<Nn, Tt> &other) {
        static_assert(N == Nn, "Vector size mismatch");
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            data[i] = static_cast<T>(other[i]);
        }
    }

    Vector(const Vector &other) = default; // copy constructor

protected:
    std::array<T, N> data;
};
}
```

`Vector2D`

```
namespace mu {
template<typename T>
class Vector2D : public Vector<2,T> {

  public:

  using Vector<2, T>::Vector; // inherit base class constructors

  Vector2D(const Vector<2, T>& other) : Vector<2, T>(other) {}

  // Vector2D specific functions, e.g. rotation
  //...

};
}
```

Examples (they should all compile)

```
// Example 1 (compiles)
mu::Vector<2, int> a{1, 2};
mu::Vector<2, float> b{a};

// Example 2 (compiles)
mu::Vector<2, int> c{1, 2};
mu::Vector2D<float> d{c};

// Example 3 (doesn't compile)
mu::Vector2D<int> e{1, 2};
mu::Vector<2, float> f{e};

// Example 4 (doesn't compile)
mu::Vector2D<int> g{1, 2};
mu::Vector2D<float> h{g};
```

Error (examples 3 & 4)

```
.../vector.h:63:27: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::array<float, 2UL>'
Vector(TArgs... args) : data_({args...}) {}
```

The code tries to call the wrong constructor instead of the one that contains the type casting. I already tried to **add another constraint** to the enable_if term but so far with no good result.

Comment: `template <std::size_t Nn, typename Tt> Vector(const Vector<Nn, Tt> &other)` can simply be `template <typename Tt> Vector(const Vector<N, Tt> &other)`.

Comment: i added the Nn as a template parameter so i could add a static_assert that gives a clearer error message as supposed to "no matching constructor found" or sth. else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jarod42 pointed me in the right direction

What i need is `&&` instead of `||` for the two arguments. However, `std::is_base_of` is not really enforcing what i want. I replaced it with `std::is_same` to check if all the arguments supplied by `...TArgs` are actually of the same type as the one that the Vector already holds, `T`.

Now, this constructor can only be called by giving it the exact `N` number of arguments that are of type `T`

```
template <typename... TArgs,
       std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(TArgs) == N && 
                        (std::is_same_v<T, TArgs> && ...), int> = 0>
Vector(TArgs... args) : data_({args...}) {}
```

Comment: `is_same` is maybe too restrictive, `mu::Vector<2, float> b{4.2f, 0}` will fail (`0` is `int` and not `float`).

Comment: yes, this is fine. I don't want to allow code like `mu::Vector<2,int> b{0, 1.5f}` which would apply implicit narrowing and result in a Vector containing `0`,`1`

Answer (score 3):

```
template <typename... TArgs,
        std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(TArgs) == N ||
                         (!std::is_base_of_v<Vector, TArgs> && ...), int> = 0>
  Vector(TArgs... args) : data({args...}) {}
```

is wrong, you probably want `&&` [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06f74a17c6f513e9)

but `std::is_convertible<TArgs, T>` or `std::is_constructible<T, TArgs>` seems more appropriate.

variadic constructor without "tag" is dangerous BTW, as it can catch easily copy constructor.

Comment: you're right. i need && instead of || for the two arguments. However, i also put a heavier restriction on this constructor instead of `std::is_base_of` (see my answer)